# Project Euler problem number 4

Tags: python

```
n = 0
for a in xrange(999, 100, -1):
    for b in xrange(a, 100, -1):
        x = a * b
        if x > n:
            s = str(a * b)
            if s == s[::-1]:
                 n = a * b
print n
```

I have a question about this solution to [the problem](http://projecteuler.net/index.php?section=problems&id=4).
I know it is right but I am wondering why in the `xrange(999,100,-1)` the `-1` is there
For the a and b for loops. Please explain. I am new to this :)

Comment: Will be great if you post URL of problem 4.

Comment: http://projecteuler.net/index.php?section=problems&id=4

Answer (score 7):

The third parameter to `xrange()` is the increment value. The default is 1, which means the counter will count in an increasing direction. To count in a decreasing direction, use -1. Your `a` counter will go from 999 to 101 (the `xrange()` iterator stops just *before* it reaches the second parameter value).

For future reference, see the [`xrange()` documentation](http://docs.python.org/library/functions.html#xrange).

Answer (score 5):

The -1 specifies a negative step. Thus moving from 999 descending to 100 (exclusive).

Answer (score 1):

`xrange` function takes three arguments: `start`, `stop` and `step`.
It returns a range of numbers starting from `start` continuing to `stop`, but not including it. If 'start' is bigger than `stop`, negative step must be provided.

So basically `xrange(999, 100, -1)` will give you `[999, 998, ..., 101]`

Answer (score 0):

It means that you are decreasing (hence the negative sign) in increments of 1, from 999 to 100

Comment: From 999 to *101*, since `range` doesn't include the end number.

Answer (score 0):

This is what I got for the project Euler #4 question:

```
def Palindrome(s):
    if s == s[::-1]:
        return True
    else:
        return False

i = 100
j = 100
greatest = 0
while (i <= 999):
    while (j <= 999):
        product = i * j
        if (product > greatest and Palindrome(str(product))):
            greatest = product
        j += 1
    j = 100
    i += 1
print "Answer: " + str(greatest)
```

-M1K3

Answer (score 0):

My Python solution:

```
container = []

for i in range(100, 999):
    for j in range(100, 999):
        num = i * j
        if str(num) == str(num)[::-1]:
            container.append(num)

print(max(container))
```

Answer (score 0):

```
__author__ = 'shreysatapara'
f=0
for a in range(100,1000):
    for b in range(100,1000):
        c=a*b
        d=c
        s=0
        x=0
        for i in range(0,len(str(c))):
            s=c%10
            x=x*10+s
            c=c//10
            if(x==d):
                if(x>f):
                    f=x
                    print(f)
```

## bingo answer is your last number in compiler....

Answer (score 0):

```
import time
start_time = time.time()
largest_number = 0
for i in range(999,100,-1):
    for j in range(i,100,-1):
        string_number = str(i * j)
        if string_number == string_number[::-1]:
            if i*j > largest_number:
                largest_number = i * j
print(largest_number)
print(time.time() - start_time," seconds")
```

Answer (score -1):

The negative one is the modifier. Basically the loops start at 999, end at 100, and get there by modifying each number by negative one.

Answer (score -1):

```
for x in range(100, 1000):
    for y in range(100, 1000):
        product = x*y
        if product > x*y:
            break
        if str(product) == str(product)[::-1] and product > 900000:
            print (x, y, product)
```

Comment: This does not even attempt to answer the question.

Comment: Please don't post code-only answers. Future readers will be grateful to see explained *why* this answers the question instead of having to infer it from the code. Also, since this is an old question, please explain how it complements *all* other answers.

Answer (score -1):

```py
def reverse(s):
    str = ""
    for i in s:
        str = i + str
    return str


MAXN = 0
for i in range(100, 1000):
    for j in range(100, 1000):
        a = i * j
        b = str(a)
        if b == reverse(b) and a > MAXN:
            MAXN = a
print(MAXN)
```

Comment: The question was asking about the solution that uses the `xrange` function. Also, please fix the indentation, and don't use `str` as a variable name because it can shadow the built-in [`str()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#func-str) function (which you also use in your code).

Comment: Please don't post code-only answers. Future readers will be grateful to see explained *why* this answers the question instead of having to infer it from the code. Also, since this is an old question, please explain how it complements *all* other answers.